# Writing CSS in JS code to remove arrow buttons from TextField

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, react-with-styles

I am building a webpage with React and Material-UI. I have a TextField element and I want to remove the arrow buttons - if I were using CSS I would use the following code:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

But I want to style the page using CSS in JS where I use `export default withStyles(styles)(FormPersonalDetails)`. How do I do this? 
`

```
const styles = theme => ({
    number: {
        // styling code goes here//
    }
});
```

render() function:

```
const { classes } = this.props;
return (
    <TextField className={classes.number} />
)
```

Comment: You are using a class?? So just add your css to App.css.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few syntax options. I have included two options below. The first one uses `className` on `TextField` and then targets the descendant `input` element. The second one applies the className directly to the `input` element via the `TextField` [`inputProps`](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props) property.

The `&` is used in both to refer to the [parent selector](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0-alpha.16#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule) (i.e. the element that the class is being applied to).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  number: {
    "& input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, & input::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
      "-webkit-appearance": "none",
      margin: 0
    }
  },
  input: {
    "&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
      "-webkit-appearance": "none",
      margin: 0
    }
  }
});

function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField type="number" className={classes.number} />
      <br />
      <TextField type="number" inputProps={{ className: classes.input }} />
    </div>
  );
}
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField remove spin buttons]